# how to change a expression in a ngFor on a selection of checkbox angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox, angular, ngfor

this is my html code

```
<tr *ngFor="let Resolution of Resolutions">
<td>{{Resolution.steps}}</td>
   <td>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">
         <div *ngFor="let Suggestion of Resolution.Suggestions">
            <label >
                <input #t (change)="actualActions(t.checked)" type="checkbox" value="{{Suggestion.item}}" checked="{{Suggestion.status}}" class="i-checks"> {{Suggestion.item}}
            </label>
         </div>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td><textarea value="{{Actualaction}}"></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

first column will display some text and in the second column it will display checkboxes using another ngFor . when i select any of the  checkboxes, in the third column i want to display whichever checkboxes are selected.

i know how to do this in jquery but not in Angular2 here when i am printing the selected values to the third column. all of the third column data is changing in the table
i want checked values of the second column of each row to display in the third column of that perticular row

Answer (score 0):

You can use `let i=index` in second for loop and pass `i with a particular object` in `change='actualActions(t.checked,i,Suggestion )` as shown below,

```
  *ngFor="let Resolution of Resolutions">
                            <td>{{Resolution.steps}}</td>
                            <td>
                            <div class="col-sm-10 ">
                                <div *ngFor="let Suggestion of Resolution.Suggestions;let i=index">
                                    <label >
                                        <input #t (change)="actualActions(t.checked,i,Suggestion )" type="checkbox" value="{{Suggestion.item}}" checked="{{Suggestion.status}}" class="i-checks"> {{Suggestion.item}}
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            </td>
                            <td><textarea value="{{Actualaction}}"></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
```

in component

```
actualActions(checked, index, obj){
   if(checked){
      //this.Actualaction=index 
      //this.Actualaction=obj.something
   }
}
```

Comment: i am getting the index and the selected value but when i am assigning it to the this.Actualaction in all the row 's third column is changing. since its an expression in each row.. how to define that it should reflect only on the same row...this result i was able to populate before also

Comment: Thats because Actualaction is a common varible for all rows. If you want to make it individual for each row, you should think about `Resoultions list` n make sure Actualaction is there in this list.